# Elementor Custom Query - Dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor

I have a custom post type 'project'. In project pages, I have a custom field 'address' which contains the value of city name like 'Islamabad', 'Lahore', 'Rawalpindi, 'Peshawar', 'Karachi', 'Gujranwala' and many more. I am developing a Projects Listing page where trying to show related projects under city-wise headings. Now I would like to get info on 2 problems:

1. Dynamic Query
2. Excluding Cities

**1. Dynamic Query**
I have a separate query for each city which I want to list under a heading. Like for heading 'Lahore', I have query Id 'projectsLahore' and in functions.php a function 'custom_query_LHR'. So, I have 4 functions for 4 cities.

```
/**
 * Update the projects widget query.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param \WP_Query $query The WordPress query instance.
 */

//   for ISLAMABAD - RAWALPINDI
function custom_query_ISB( $query ) {
    
    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'address',
        'value' => [ 'islamabad', 'rawalpindi' ],
        'compare' => 'in',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/projectsIslamabad', 'custom_query_ISB' );


//   for LAHORE
function custom_query_LHR( $query ) {
    
    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'address',
        'value' => 'lahore',
        'compare' => '==',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/projectsLahore', 'custom_query_LHR' );

// AND SO ON...
```

Is there a way to make the query dynamic? like we write only one function and based on the query id, it decides which projects to filter...

**2. Excluding Cities**
I have a heading called 'Other Cities'. How to make a query for this heading so it excludes some cities and show all other projects?